# is this a decent model fit?

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, overfitting, fitting, beta-distribution

I am new to linear modeling (first time using glmm, brms, etc). I am just wondering if the family and formula I am using are decent for my data. I am running a beta distribution for my percentage data. The percentage data comes from count data of how many food particles a sponge eats from different food types. there are 5 food types and I divide the consumed particles by the total. The counts can be high from 1000s to 100,000s so I was under the impression that I could consider them continuous rather than discrete ( I can seem to get beta.binomial distribution to work for glmmTMB or binomial to work from brms so I was sticking with beta distribution). I ran my code which was succesful

```
brmwo3way = brm(Redecimal ~ Region+food+genus +Region:food + Region:genus + genus:food + (1|sample), family = Beta(link =  "logit"), iter = 2000, control = list(max_treedepth = 10), data = REdata)
```

I just don't know if the model is good enough to trust, I have a small data set 16 sponges in two of the sets and 8 sponges in the other 2 so I don't want to over complicate it with the small sample size.
I ran the pp_check function for brmsfit

```
pp = pp_check(brmwo3way)
pp + theme_bw()
```

and I got this

[image]

I just ran it with random slopes which made it look a lot better

```
brmwo3waywslope = brm(Redecimal ~ Region+food+genus +Region:food + Region:genus + genus:food + (1 + food|sample), family = Beta(link =  "logit"), iter = 6000, control = list(max_treedepth = 10, adapt_delta = 0.85), data = REdata)
```

[image]

This ones seems good, should I continue on to next steps with this one?

So I did the loo and got these outputs

```
loo1 <- loo(brmwo3way, save_psis = TRUE)
loo2 <- loo(brmwo3waywslope, save_psis = TRUE)
```

```
> loo1

Computed from 4000 by 232 log-likelihood matrix

         Estimate   SE
elpd_loo    335.6 27.1
p_loo        43.4  9.5
looic      -671.2 54.1
------
Monte Carlo SE of elpd_loo is NA.

Pareto k diagnostic values:
                         Count Pct.    Min. n_eff
(-Inf, 0.5]   (good)     219   94.4%   562       
 (0.5, 0.7]   (ok)        10    4.3%   254       
   (0.7, 1]   (bad)        2    0.9%   121       
   (1, Inf)   (very bad)   1    0.4%   9         
See help('pareto-k-diagnostic') for details.
```

and

```
> loo2

Computed from 12000 by 232 log-likelihood matrix

         Estimate   SE
elpd_loo    511.6 14.9
p_loo       181.0 10.0
looic     -1023.2 29.9
------
Monte Carlo SE of elpd_loo is NA.

Pareto k diagnostic values:
                         Count Pct.    Min. n_eff
(-Inf, 0.5]   (good)       4    1.7%   663       
 (0.5, 0.7]   (ok)        51   22.0%   139       
   (0.7, 1]   (bad)      162   69.8%   10        
   (1, Inf)   (very bad)  15    6.5%   0         
See help('pareto-k-diagnostic') for details.
```

and here is the ppc_loo_pit_overlay for loo1 and loo2

[image]

[image]

So it seems that the model that looks better for the pp_check and the ppc_loo_pit_overlay has terrible Pareto k values.

Here is the code for the custom model for beta_binomial that used. I change my model to match how they did it using the data consumed food and incurrent food rather than the percentage from those two

```
beta_binomial2 <- custom_family(
  "beta_binomial2", dpars = c("mu", "phi"),
  links = c("logit", "log"), lb = c(NA, 0),
  type = "int", vars = "vint1[n]"
)


stan_funs <- "
  real beta_binomial2_lpmf(int y, real mu, real phi, int T) {
    return beta_binomial_lpmf(y | T, mu * phi, (1 - mu) * phi);
  }
  int beta_binomial2_rng(real mu, real phi, int T) {
    return beta_binomial_rng(T, mu * phi, (1 - mu) * phi);
  }
"

stanvars <- stanvar(scode = stan_funs, block = "functions")

brmbetabin = brm(incurrent | vint(consumed) ~ Region+food+genus +Region:food + Region:genus + genus:food + (1|sample), family = beta_binomial2, data = REdata, stanvars = stanvars)
```

the model was able to start running however I got an error

```
SAMPLING FOR MODEL '56e4d552c3161029f952436f8350b609' NOW (CHAIN 1).
Chain 1: Rejecting initial value:
Chain 1:   Log probability evaluates to log(0), i.e. negative infinity.
Chain 1:   Stan can't start sampling from this initial value.
```

I would like to just use the percentage data so I tried to change it so I took out the vint1 from the code and I changes it a couple times and kept getting different errors in how it was written

```
beta_binomial2 <- custom_family(
  "beta_binomial2", dpars = c("mu", "phi"),
  links = c("logit", "log"), lb = c(NA, 0),
  type = "real"
)


stan_funs <- "
  real beta_binomial2_lpmf(int y, real mu, real phi, real T) {
    return beta_binomial_lpmf(y | T, mu * phi, (1 - mu) * phi);
  }
  int beta_binomial2_rng(real mu, real phi, int T) {
    return beta_binomial_rng(T, mu * phi, (1 - mu) * phi);
  }
"

stanvars <- stanvar(scode = stan_funs, block = "functions")

brmbetabin = brm(Redecimal ~ Region+food+genus +Region:food + Region:genus + genus:food + (1|sample), family = beta_binomial2, data = REdata, stanvars = stanvars)
```

I get different errors for the stan_funs code about the lmpf or rng

```
SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:
No matches for: 

  beta_binomial_lpmf(int, real, real, real)

Available argument signatures for beta_binomial_lpmf:

  beta_binomial_lpmf(int, int, real, real)
  beta_binomial_lpmf(int, int, real, real[ ])
  beta_binomial_lpmf(int, int, real, vector)
  beta_binomial_lpmf(int, int, real, row_vector)
  beta_binomial_lpmf(int, int, real[ ], real)
  beta_binomial_lpmf(int, int, real[ ], real[ ])
  beta_binomial_lpmf(int, int, real[ ], vector)
```

or

```
SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:
No matches for: 

  beta_binomial2_lpmf(int, real, real)

Available argument signatures for beta_binomial2_lpmf:

  beta_binomial2_lpmf(int, real, real, int)

 error in 'model59b436405ba8_file59b4ba57408' at line 65, column 54
  -------------------------------------------------
    63:   if (!prior_only) {
    64:     for (n in 1:N) {
    65:       target += beta_binomial2_lpmf(Y[n] | mu[n], phi);
                                                             ^
    66:     }
  -------------------------------------------------
```

I try different switches from continuous to discrete data but have been unable to get it to run.

Comment: Is `genus` a characteristic of the sample? If so, then you would ideally want to allow the slope for food to vary across samples before interacting food with other variables. The fit seems to bear that out as well.

Comment: yes, each sample belongs to one of the two genera. So are you saying I should change the formula to reflect that somehow? I am very new to modeling and am unsure of how  everything should be placed.

Answer (score 0):

Your model statement reflects a mixed model with fixed or non-varying predictors `Region` and `genus`, their interaction, and then varying predictor `food` along with its interactions with `Region` and `genus`. We know that `food` is a varying predictor because it is included in the random part of the model `(1+food|sample)`. Thus each sample is allowed to have its own unique association between `food` and `Redecimal`, the outcome.

This model seems to provide a good fit to the data. You can additionally compare the two models using the `loo` function. For your models:

```
loo1 <- loo(brmwo3way, save_psis = TRUE)
loo2 <- loo(brmwo3waywslope, save_psis = TRUE)
compare(loo1, loo2) # looking for model with higher LOO value
```

You can further examine the LOO-probability integral transform (LOO-PIT) plots for each model. You are looking for the simulates to follow a uniform distribution. Since you produced the PPC plots, I assume you have already calculated yrep for each of the models. Assuming that you called the first model's yrep `yrep1`, the LOO-PIT plots can be produced as such:

```
library(bayesplot) 

ppc_loo_pit_overlay(yrep = yrep1, y = Redecimal, lw = weights(loo1$psis_object)) + ggtitle("LOO-PIT Model 1") #first model

ppc_loo_pit_overlay(yrep = yrep1, y = Redecimal, lw = weights(loo1$psis_object)) + ggtitle("LOO-PIT Model 2") #second model
```

You can find a very helpful guide for Bayesian modeling and diagnostics [here](https://www.monicaalexander.com/posts/2020-28-02-bayes_viz/).

Comment: So I edited the question putting in the comments you suggested. The loo seemed good for the Pareto k values for model 1 but it was terrible for model2, which had a better fit for the pp_check as well as the LOO-PIT plot (although they both didn't seem to get the peck at the center). Now I am confused as to what to do next.

Comment: They say you shouldn't trust the Pareto k values that are over 0.7 but it seems to predict the model better than model 1. I read that model 2 just might be highly flexible which is why it fits the model better or that my priors are weak ( I wouldn't know what to change for that). Could over dispersion have something to do with it since I am running just a beta distribution and brms does not have a beta_binomial distribution and I didn't really understand the custom distribution process for it.

Comment: Before deciding, I would suggest you implement the beta-binomial custom family as outlined in the `brms` vignette. See how that impacts these model fit diagnostics and plots. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_customfamilies.html#the-beta-binomial-distribution

Comment: I have tried that but I can't get it to work, I just get a lot of errors for the stan_funs section. I will post them in the question, any suggestions on what to put.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose what is going on. You may want to post a question about it on the Stan Forums dedicated to brms: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/c/interfaces/brms

Comment: Alright, I will try there. If I can't get the beta-binomial to work, what would be your suggestion as to what to try and do next? Should I look into making my own prior or do you know something else I might try?